# Setting Symfony2 security.context User data after login

Tags: php, symfony

Using Symfony2 I want to augment the `security.content` user after login with information obtained after login.

So in the login success code I do the following in `AccountController`:

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

// Get everything we'll ever need for this user
$user->fillDetails($this, $this->container);

$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());

// Give it to the security context
$this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);

return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('AccountBundle_homepage'));
```

If I immediately retrieve the user again after calling `setToken()` this information that is set in the User object in `fillDetails()` is still present.

However in the controller action for `AccountBundle_homepage` when I get the user using

```php
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

The extra information I set in `fillDetails()` is no longer there, or `0`.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Not really sure about this, but you probably need to persist the user to the database (or wherever your users are kept)

Comment: Yep, @carlosGranados is right. In each request Symfony2 calls `$userProvider->refreshUser()` method after loading the token from session, which usually loads user from database or other data source defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security context creates a token on each request, that means you can't modify a token, redirect the user and expect getting data set on the previous token. If you don't persist your user, it won't work. The user is reloaded on each request too.

You can find more information about the token here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html#the-token

Comment: I figured as much when I thought about it.